# Verilog: Aligning valid and invalid bytes from a dynamic input

Tags: verilog, fpga

I'm trying to design a system that takes an 8 byte data input and an 8 bit valid input every clock cycle where each bit on the valid input either validates or invalidates a data byte.

```
input wire [63:0] d_in;
input wire [7:0]  v_in;
```

The program should process d_in aligning all the valid bytes as follows.

(where B is a valid byte and X is an invalid byte)

Instance 1:

```
d_in = B1 B2 X X B3 X B4 B5

d_out = B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 X X X
```

Instance 2:

```
d_in = X B1 B2 B3 X B4 B5 B6

d_out = B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 X X
```

I've mainly worked with algorithms before where all bit manipulation was the same every iteration e.g.`assign d_out [7:0] = d_in [15:8];` but the fact that the quantity and order of valid bytes can change with every data input means this strategy cannot be used.

My question:

Is there a way to realise this function in using Verilog or VHDL? If so can someone point me towards a high level solution or some relevant reading so I can understand this concept better. I think if I understood at a high level then I'd be able to take a stab a coding it but currently I'm not even sure what I need to be coding.

Thanks
Zach

Comment: Ouch! If there is truly no set rule/pattern and it could be any number of bytes at any position - then you will end up with some pretty deep logic. Knowing that, you should use the FPGAs pipelining ability to pre-calculate some nested logics, breaking up the depth and also giving some timing relief for the tools.
That's assuming you don't want to buffer the input and shift out bytes, but that would equally not be trivial.

Comment: @fpga_magik If you don't mind can you expand on what you mean by buffer the input signal and shift out bytes? I am interested in this solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you asked for high level I will give a pseudocode example of something that might work, or at least get you going.

```
d_out = '0; //Assuming that the X bytes can be set to zero in the output.
bytes = 0;
for i in range(8)
 if v_in[i]
   d_out[bytes*8 +: 8] = d_in[i*8 +: 8] //Note the +: notation which is not pseudo, but verilog.
   bytes++
```

Now perform this sequential code in an always block and you should be set.

Note: How the synthesized result from this will look is not entierly clear to me, but i suspect it will generate quite a bit of hardware.

Comment: Thanks for input. I understand this approach logically however I'm worried that there would be latency issues since there is new data input every clock cycle and a this solution cannot be pipelined (to my knowledge)

Comment: You are correct to worry about that. I suspect the logic will be deep. However, it should be easy enough to implement, so you can give it a swing and see what comes out. In terms of pipelining I don't think this solution is much help. But a thought about merging occurred to me. That is, sort of like merge-sort but only with sorting X bytes to the end of the byte array. Not sure if it is a viable solution.

Comment: Was able to pipeline the original solution by instantiating each loop iteration as a separate module with registers inbetween to store the module outputs in order to create the pipeline. It's nasty in terms of area but an area efficient design wasn't a requirement as It just needed to work functionally and meet the timing requirements. There's definitely more elegant solutions out there though

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar but not quite.

Input data into a FIFO, pre-calculate a byte-enable with the FIFO entries.
On the output side, read the the byte enable portions and use it to shift out bytes. So there are only eight conditions to satisfy for the byte enable...

```
1 byte, byteEn(0 downto 1) = "10", shift left 1 byte
2 bytes, byteEn(0 downto 2) = "110", shift left 2 bytes
3 bytes, byteEn(0 downto 3) = "1110", shift left 3 bytes
```

...and so on...

As you shift, read in the next word using the FIFOs read enable. 
Note you will need to take care of when the FIFO is empty but not halt the pipeline so data already present continues to be shifted out.

Not sure how complicated it will be as I have glossed over it a bit.